# didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: only called in background when connected to xcode

Tags: ios, background, notifications

I know this question has been asked in the past but none of the responses i have seen to date seem to solve my problem.

I am attempting to handle push notifications in the background on my iOS app, but for some reason the didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: method only gets invoked in debug mode when the app is connected to xcode.

I am sending the notifications using PushSharp, and i have tried pretty much everything. I set content-available to 1, tried setting sound/alert to "", and even tried setting the priority to 1, 5, and 10 (i know its the default but worth a shot) but to no avail.

When i launch the app from xcode and press the home button, i am able to get the method to invoke by sending a push notification. However, if i stop the app, start it again on the device, press the home button, and send a push notification, the method never gets called.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Facing the same problem here

Answer (score 0):

A few observations:

- When running the app attached to the debugger, it artificially changes the app lifecycle, keeping it running in the background. Usually apps are suspended when the user leaves them (and eventually “jettisoned”, i.e., terminated, after a while). It sounds that you might not have turned on “Remote notifications” [background capability](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-background-execution-modes)).
- I also generally test push notifications with a signed build, generated from Xcode‘s “Product” » “Archive”. See [Testing a release build](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/testing-a-release-build).
- Finally, I would suggest checking to see what error message you received from the APNS, if any. Previously I have used third-party apps to test APNS, but Apple now has their [push console](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/push-notifications-console/) for this.

  [image]